# How do I prevent "s from turning into ß with babel?

Tags: input-encodings, characters, german

I'm writing a German document and thus I need äÄöÖüÜß to work. However I don't use it this way: "a"A"o... I just type äÄö... 
My Problem is that **"Test" s** is displayed as **"Testß**

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding=latin1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}
"Test" s
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `utf8` instead of `latin1` and it should work IMHO. Or it is a `ngerman` issue.

Comment: You should never use straight quotes. Use `\glqq Term here\grqq` if you want quotes in the output or resort to a package like `csquotes`.

Comment: @sztruks I tried using `utf8` in both places. Sadly that didn't change anything

Comment: @TeXnician using `  \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}` and `\enquote{test} s` it works and I get the left one beeing down as well. Thanks

Comment: the use of `"` is an error you should use left and right quotes

Comment: Add a character: `"Test" s` to `"Test"\ s`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The character `"` should never be used in running text to denote quotes. For double English quotes, use

```
``Test'' s
```

If you want German style quotes, use

```
"`Test"' s
```

With UTF-8 input, you can use

```
“Test” s
```

for English style and

```
„Test“ s
```

for German style. The alternative `\glqq Test\grqq\ s` is less convenient.

Examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with LaTeX after 2018-04-01
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{upquote,booktabs} % for the table

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Style} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Input} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Output} \\
\midrule
English & \verb|``Test'' s| & ``Test'' s
\\
English & \verb|“Test” s| & “Test” s
\\
German & \verb|"`Test"' s| & "`Test"' s
\\
German & \verb|„Test“ s| & „Test“ s
\\
German & \verb|\glqq Test\grqq\ s| & \glqq Test\grqq\ s
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Didn't know `"``. Congratulations to 700k btw.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Table 1 in `texdoc babel-ngerman`. Thanks!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Typo, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Solution 3: use left and right quotes in the source too, as [David Carlisle auggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462728/s-turns-into-%c3%9f-at-places-i-dont-want-to-disable-s-to-turn-into-%c3%9f#comment1163934_462728):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}
“Test”s, and “test” s too (but I’d use “test”~s, then).
\end{document}
```

This is the output I get:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: +1: Good point: But I cannot find them on my German keyboard (as direct keys).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I have a Mac with an “international English” keyboard, so I can type them rather easily.  I couldn’t stand using LaTeX with a different keyboard! :-)

Comment: @GuM My advice is: buy whatever keyboard you prefer, so long as it is International English.

Comment: @egreg Never have heard of international English keyboards :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use **latin1** (which is ISO 8859-1), then I have collected two solutions which are already mentioned in the comments.

> The problem is, that in some cases* `"A, "O, "U, "a, "o, "u, "s` are
>   commands for special characters (instead of `\"A, \"O or \ss{}` for
>   example). So LaTeX cannot know what you mean in your example.
>
> *Depending on the loaded packages, in this case, the `babel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\section*{They are all the same regarding the ß}

\begin{itemize}
\item "Test" s
\item " s
\item "s
\item But: "\ s % Thanks to comment of user Dũng Vũ
\end{itemize}

\section*{Solution 1: Use \texttt{babel}'s quotation marks}
% See also https://www.namsu.de/Extra/befehle/Anfuehrungszeichen.html
% https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen
% \glqq --> German Left Double Quote
% \grqq --> German Right Double Quote
% \glq --> German Left Single Quote
% \grq --> German Right Single Quote

\begin{itemize}
\item \glqq Test\grqq\ s (Don't forget the \textbackslash\ after the command)
\item \glq Test\grq\ s
\end{itemize}

\section*{Solution 2: Use the \texttt{csquote} package}
% For more information, have a look at the manual
% https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes

\enquote{Test} s

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** On the screenshot, you see on the bottom right that I use the correct encoding in the editor, in this case ISO-8859-1 which is latin1.

Comment: @dũng-vũ I mentioned you in the "solution".

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the qoute character (") to change text to umlaute can be done using `\shorthandoff{"}`. To turn it back on, use `\shorthandon{"}`.

Both commands can be used anywhere in the document but not in the preamble. So to disable it for the whole document put it after `\begin{document}`